# React js useState throws error when state is passed as prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing an ecommerce webshop using React js and Commerce.js
I am very confused as I am not able to identify the precise problem. But here's how it's happening:

My App.js:

```
const App = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

  const fetchProducts = async () => {
    const { data } = await commerce.products.list();
    setProducts(data);
  };

  const fetchCart = async () => {
    setCart(await commerce.cart.retrieve());
  };

  const handleAddToCart = async (productId, quantity) => {
    const item = await commerce.cart.add(productId, quantity);
    setCart(item.cart);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProducts();
    fetchCart();
  }, []);

  console.log(cart);

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar totalItems={cart.total_items} />
      {/* <Products products={products} onAddToCart={handleAddToCart} /> */}
      {/* <Cart cartItems={cart} /> */}
    </>
  );
```

Now when I uncomment the `<Cart cartItems={cart} />`, React js Throws an error
This is the error in from the console

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {raw, formatted, formatted_with_symbol, formatted_with_code}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Interestingly enough, the single item is being passed on through the Cart.js but not without the error.

Here's Cart.js for Reference

```
const Cart = ({ cartItems }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const EmptyCart = () => {
    return (
      <Typography variant="subtitle1">
        You have no items in your cart. Start adding some :)
      </Typography>
    );
  };

  const FilledCart = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
          {cartItems.line_items.map((item) => (
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={4} key={item.id}>
              <CartItem items={item} />
            </Grid>
          ))}
        </Grid>
        <div className={classes.cardDetails}>
          <Typography variant="h4">
            Subtotal: {cartItems.subtotal.formatted_with_symbol}
          </Typography>
          <div>
            <Button
              className={classes.emptyButton}
              size="large"
              type="button"
              variant="contained"
              color="secondary"
            >
              Empty Cart
            </Button>
            <Button
              className={classes.checkoutButton}
              size="large"
              type="button"
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
            >
              Checkout
            </Button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  };

  if (!cartItems.line_items)
    return <Typography variant="h4">Loading...</Typography>;

  return (
    <Container>
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />
      <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h3">
        Your Shopping Cart
      </Typography>
      {!cartItems.line_items.length ? <EmptyCart /> : <FilledCart />}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Update:

Here's what Cart object looks like
[image]

Comment: Can you please show how `cart` object looks like?

Comment: What does the `cart`/`cartItems` look like? Also the error might be caused by `CartItem` too?

Comment: I would also suggest to init the cart state as null, your cart looks like an object not an array

Comment: Updated the question with Cart object.

Comment: Everything seems to work fine when I comment out Cart component. Navbar populates the cart items total without any error. Error is produced as soon as the Cart component is added.

Comment: My guess is the issue is even further down: `<CartItem items={item} />`. Can you post the CartItem code?